# Get Time values from angular material datepicker with custom format on change

Tags: angular-material, datepicker, datetime-format

I have date component build on mate-datepicker.

```
mat-form-field> 
    <mat-label>{{name}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput 
      [matDatepicker]="datepicker"
      [value]="value"
      (dateChange)="dateChange($event)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #datepicker>
  </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I use custom format like this

```
var FORMAT = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: '',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: '',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

When the dateInput field is empty, the datepicker component returns the selected date in the default format, such as "2023-02-22T11:00:20+01:00". In this default format, I can modify the time values, and the datepicker recognizes the changes.
However, when I use a custom format in the dateInput field, such as `DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`, I am able to modify the date values, but any changes to the time values result in them being reset to 0.

I tried multiple date time formats or only setting format in either parse or display dateInput.
I'm stuck in two possible results. One is when I'm able to change time in input, but format is not desired. Or the second, when date is in desired format, but I cannot change time in input.

Is there a solution for editing time in datepicker input with custom format?

I know it is datepicker, not dateTIMEpicker, but I assumed, that at least the input values could be changed.